# An internal error occurred during: "C/C++ Indexer"

Tags: c++, eclipse, autocomplete, indexing, ide

For some reasons eclipse starts showing me this message recently and after that auto-completing and intellisense stop working

```
 An internal error occurred during: "C/C++ Indexer".
tried to access method java.lang.Object.clone()Ljava/lang/Object; from class org.eclipse.cdt.internal.core.dom.parser.cpp.semantics.SemanticUtil
```

I searched a lot but with no value!

Answer (score 0):

Generally changing params Xms and Xmx to something like:

-Xms2048m

-Xmx2048m

in eclipse.ini file should fix it